# htaccess RewriteCond & RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've pulled most of whatever was left of my hair out on this one, and my feeling is that the answer is quite simple.

I have a URL:

https://www.example.com/?download={rest of query string here}

and I want to rewrite that into

https://www.example.com/index.php?download={rest of query string here}

The user doesn't need to be redirected. But I cannot figure this out. I tried 50 or 60 different things and I'm hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

In the htaccess file in your document root?

Or try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^download=
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Actually the reason why I need this is because in this root, I need index.html to be the default. But because this is WordPress, I need to "inject" index.php into two URLs when called.

Comment: Hi Jon. On this website your edit works:

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be

However when used in the standard WordPress-edited htaccess file, the URL is not rewritten.

Comment: @Russ did you put the rule before any wordpress rules?

Comment: Both before and after, yeah :( I do sincerely appreciate your help though.